# What is an algebraic formula for the standard error of the intercept in multiple linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, standard-error

Please don't give me the answer using the matrix formulation of regression analysis.  I am not using the matrix formulation.

I know what the expression for the intercept is for simple (one-variable) linear regression, but I am unable to generalize that expression for the multiple-variable case and produce a correct answer.

Comment: The answer is the square root of the ratio of two determinants (times a root mean squared residual value).  How does one express that without matrices??

Comment: While it may be physically possible to write something down, in the general case it would be considerably easier to learn to use matrices. They exist because they yield a great economy of both effort and concept. You will be able to understand things you could not see from formulas that avoided them.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thank you for your comment.  I can use the matrix approach to OLS with the best of them, but if one uses the maximum likelihood or minimizing the squared error approaches, then there is no matrix from which to compute the standard errors.  In these cases one needs an algebraic expression for Std Error of the intercept.  Such expressions exist for regression coefficients, but I cannot find one for the intercept.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. You need more detail in your question about what, exactly you're trying to do. 2. I think you either misunderstand something about regression or you have omitted an important detail. Multiple regression via maximum likelihood would still make use of matrices for example.